# Why won't this react native header follow the style I've applied?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

Please take a look at my online project I created in snack
https://snack.expo.dev/@sujono/7c4a2d?platform=android .

So in Role2.js I did set the values but the result isn't what i expected. This is so weird. I even tried it locally, but it still didn't work. Can't I change the style of react native header? If I can, please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Can you specify a little, where you want to change the color of header. Do you want different color for different screens? or you want to change header color dynamically from some screen. Although my recommendation is `not to use react navigation header` but make your own custom one. It is more easy to handle.

Comment: I want to customize the height, corner radius, and add some buttons. Yeah some people said I should use new header component but I have no idea how to assign it as header.

Comment: Check through the answer session. There are code examples there

Answer (score 1):

You can create your header component that you can use across your application. Styling and other events can be handled inside this header.
Also ensure you set headerShown to false in your navigators so the default react navigation header is hidden

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Header = ({title, navigation, bgColor}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{height: 40, backgroundColor: bgColor}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
        <Text style={{ color: 'white'}}>Back</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={{flex: 1, color: 'white', textAlign: 'center', padding: 10}}>
        {title}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to react native and I don't know how to use the custom component as header. Could you please provide me with an example?

Comment: I will edit the answer to provide an example

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `Custom header`, And you have to call it on every screen.

Usually we have three main component on Header `Container`, `context` & `functionality`.

`(context  = title & icons on both sides)`

So, Header Component be like this,

```js
const MyHeader = ({
  title,
  iconRight,
  iconLeft,
  onpressRight,
  onpressLeft,
}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Icons
        size={20}
        name={iconLeft}
        onPress={onpressLeft}
        style={styles.iconStyle}
      />
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      <Icons
        size={20}
        name={iconRight}
        onPress={onpressRight}
        style={styles.iconStyle}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

This is the main structure, now you have to handle some cases like, when icon is missing text should still be centered, and other according to your need.

This is [**Expo Snack**](https://snack.expo.dev/@talhamaqsood890/stackoverflow---custom-header) for the complete component and usage.  I will make nesseccery changes but the main concept will be same.

Comment: Thank you. This kind of header works well

Comment: Can you mark answer as accepted!