# React Native double header

Tags: react-native, expo

I have problem with react native app. I created app with expo and implemented Tab Navigator but I have problem with double header, My Tab Navigator header works, but I don't understand where from upper header is coming from, so now I have double header issue.
[image]

I looked a lot on google, watched tutorials and for some reason then watching tutorial that default header is not existing in examples. How can I fix this?

My index.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Navigation from "../Navigation";

const Home = () => {
    return <Navigation />;
}
export default Home;
```

Navigation.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import ProfileScreen from "./screens/ProfileScreen";
import FeedScreen from "./screens/FeedScreen";
import {colors} from "./constants/theme";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function Navigation() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
                    let iconName;

                    if (route.name === 'Feed') {
                        iconName = "home";
                    } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
                        iconName = "user"
                    }

                    return <AntDesign name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
                },
                tabBarActiveTintColor: colors.lightBlue,
                tabBarInactiveTintColor: colors.primaryDark,
                tabBarShowLabel: false,
            })}
        >
            <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}
```

Also _layout.js if needed

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

const Layout = () => {
    const [fontsLoaded, fontError] = useFonts({
        DMBold: require('../assets/fonts/DMSans-Bold.ttf'),
        DMMedium: require('../assets/fonts/DMSans-Medium.ttf'),
        DMRegular: require('../assets/fonts/DMSans-Regular.ttf'),
    });

    const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
        if (fontsLoaded || fontError) {
            await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        }
    }, [fontsLoaded, fontError]);

    if (!fontsLoaded && !fontError) {
        return null;
    }

    return <Stack onLayout={onLayoutRootView} />;
}

export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `headerShown:false`

```js
<Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}/>
```

After that you'll have to make your own `custom header`, i've already answer that before here - [Why won't this react native header follow the style I've applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77403180/why-wont-this-react-native-header-follow-the-style-ive-applied/77407986#77407986)

So basically, this is [**Expo Snack**](https://snack.expo.dev/@talhamaqsood890/stackoverflow---custom-header) for a custom header.

Comment: Ok, but how now to update header title and header style? Because if i add this option, only "index" header left, "Feed" header is disabled now

Comment: see this [stackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77403180/why-wont-this-react-native-header-follow-the-style-ive-applied/77407986#77407986), i will update the answer too.

Comment: did you upadate? Thanks in advance

Comment: Check now, and see if answer solves you issue, basically upper is coming from `Tab.Navigator` once you put  `headerShown:false` in `screenOptions` it will be disable. And you can use your own `header`. Is there anything that i am missing, i can help with?

Comment: Actually it didn't solved my issue. What I did was install new app with `npx create-expo-app`. This app with double header was installed with `npx create-expo-app@latest -e with-router`. That solved my issue, because by default there was no header in new app.

Comment: Okay, good to hear, you were able to solve the error.